# Python -- Remove dictionary from multiple nested list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to remove all of dict element in 'qas' list when its f1 is not 1.0.

Here is the list:

```
test_list = [
    {'paragraphs': [{
        'qas':[
            {'q':'abc','id':'123','a':['4','d'],'f1':1.0},
            {'q':'dsf','id':'343','a':['6','d'],'f1':0.5},
            {'q':'wre','id':'565','a':['4','u'],'f1':0.2}
        ]}
    ]},
    
    {'paragraphs': [{
        'qas':[
            {'q':'ujn','id':'874','a':['4','d'],'f1':1.0},
            {'q':'yht','id':'454','a':['5','d'],'f1':0.7},
            {'q':'nth','id':'676','a':['4','j'],'f1':0.4}
        ]}
    ]},
]
```

My expect result is:

```
test_list = [
    
    {'paragraphs': [{
        'qas':[
            {'q':'abc','id':'123','a':['4','d'],'f1':1.0}
        ]}
    ]},
    
    {'paragraphs': [{
        'qas':[
            {'q':'ujn','id':'874','a':['4','d'],'f1':1.0}
        ]}
    ]},
    
]
```

My current code:

```
for i in range(len(test_list)): 
    for j in range(len(test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'])):
        if test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'][j]['f1'] != 1:
            del test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'][j]
```

However I got an index error:

```
      1 for i in range(len(test_list)):
      2     for j in range(len(test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'])):
----> 3         if test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'][j]['f1'] != 1:
      4             del test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'][j]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

There are multiple layers of nested list and dict. Not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: You just want the first item in the `qas` key?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this can do the job.

```
for i in range(len(test_list)):
  test_list[i]["paragraphs"][0]["qas"] = test_list[i]["paragraphs"][0]["qas"][:1]

print(test_list)
```

Output -

```
[{'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'a': ['4', 'd'],
      'f1': 1.0,
      'id': '123',
      'q': 'abc'}]}]},
 {'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'a': ['4', 'd'],
      'f1': 1.0,
      'id': '874',
      'q': 'ujn'}]}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I should have explained the question more clear. This is just a toy example generated by me. f1 = 1 doesn't have to be the 1st element of the 'qas' list.

Comment: @DianaLiu I can be any item?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it worked, but wanted to learn easier way to get this done.

```
import itertools

tmp = []
for i in range(len(test_list)): 
    for j in range(len(test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'])):
        if test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'][j]['f1'] != 1:
            tmp.append(False)
        else:
            tmp.append(True)        
    test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'] = list(itertools.compress(test_list[i]['paragraphs'][0]['qas'],tmp))
```